# SQL Server UPDATE Trigger - breaking things

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I have an UPDATE statement that, long story short, runs every half minute. This statement is in Powershell so don't mind the variable syntax...

```
UPDATE dbo.MobileLeases 
SET IPAddress = '$($l.IPAddress)', 
    OwnerName = '$($l.OwnerName)', 
    Building = '$($l.Building)', 
    TimeOn = '$($l.Time)', 
    LeaseExpiry = '$($l.LeaseExpiry)', 
    Phone = '$($l.Phone)', 
    OwnerEmail = '$($l.OwnerEmail)' 
WHERE PhysicalAddress = '$($l.DeviceID)';
```

This part works great and I have no problem updating these columns. It updates *multiple rows* each time it runs.

I have an update trigger I am trying to put on this table, `dbo.MobileLeases`. When the `Building` column is updated in `dbo.MobileLeases`, I want to perform an `INSERT` into another table, `dbo.LeaseAudit`.

The `insert into` seems to work for the first update after the trigger is in place. After that, the scheduled `UPDATE` statement (from Powershell) stops working! Which is confusing to me, but here is the trigger...

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_LeaseAudit] 
ON [dbo].[MobileLeases]
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE (Building)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.LeaseAudit(PhysicalAddress, DeviceName, OwnerName, Building, TimeOn, IPAddress)
           SELECT 
               i.PhysicalAddress, i.DeviceName, i.OwnerName, i.Building,
               i.TimeOn, i.IPAddress
           FROM
               MobileLeases AS m
           INNER JOIN 
               inserted AS i on m.PhysicalAddress = i.PhysicalAddress
           INNER JOIN 
               deleted AS d on m.PhysicalAddress = d.PhysicalAddress
           WHERE 
               m.Building <> d.Building
        END
END
```

As you can see I am trying to `INSERT INTO` `dbo.LeaseAudit` when `(Building)` is updated on `dbo.MobileLeases`, WHERE the old update value (`d.Building`) is different to the new value (`m.Building`).

I guess my biggest question is how is this trigger breaking the initial update query? With the trigger in place, the scheduled update statement stops working. When I remove the trigger, everything works again.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Can you further describe not working?  Is there an error message?

Comment: @JoeC Good thinking. I have done a test and received this error, 'Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure trigger_LeaseAudit, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 46]
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__LeaseAud__27FF486881664DB5'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.LeaseAudit'. The duplicate key value is (90-b6-86-41-3d-6a).
The statement has been terminated.' SO... I guess I understand that it is not able to insert a new row into LeaseAudit when the PK already exists (though I need it to) but I guess this trigger kills the entire transaction, and MobileLeases cannot be updated either?

Comment: @JoeC I removed the PK from my audit table and I think it works fine now. Sorry to bother =/. Such a simple oversight. I will test further and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the `UPDATE` transaction was failing as a whole.

The update trigger configured on tableA is designed to insert a new row on tableB, when tableA.column1 is updated.

The insert statement includes a column that *was* set as a PK on tableB. Obviously, the insert statement could not insert a duplicate value in the PK column, so the entire update was bombing.

The solution for me was to remove the PK attribute from tableB.PK. It is an audit table, so I should not miss it.

Thank you